# Problem with tm_map(removeWords, stopwords("english")

Tags: r

I am trying to mess around with some R analytics. I have downloaded 10 TED talks file and save them as text. I am struggling with using removeWords stopwords

```
source("Project_Functions.R")
getwd()
# ==== 
# Load the PDF data
# pdf.loc <- file.path("data") # folder "PDF Files" with PDFs
# myFiles <- normalizePath(list.files(path = pdf.loc, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)) # Get the path (chr-vector) of PDF file names
# # Extract content from PDF files
# Docs.corpus <- Corpus(URISource(myFiles), readerControl = list(reader = readPDF(engine = "xpdf")))

# ==== 
# Load TED Talks Data
myFiles <- normalizePath(list.files(pattern = "txt",  full.names = TRUE))
Docs.corpus <- Corpus(URISource(myFiles), readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))
length(Docs.corpus)
#Docs.corpus <-tm_map(Docs.corpus, tolower)
Docs.corpus <-tm_map(Docs.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
Docs.corpus <-tm_map(Docs.corpus, removePunctuation)
Docs.corpus <-tm_map(Docs.corpus, removeNumbers)
Docs.corpus <-tm_map(Docs.corpus, stripWhitespace)
```

However, when I run:

```
dtm <-DocumentTermMatrix(Docs.corpus)
dtm$dimnames$Terms
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
freq <- subset(freq, freq > 10)
```

It still shows some words that I don't want like "and", "just"..etc..

I have tried researching and using [[:punct:]] and other methods but they don't work.

Please help, thank you

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem with "and", but it's possible that some of the words you want removed aren't actually stopwords--"just" isn't one.  If you enter `stopwords()` into the console, you can print the default list.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why, so the order of the tm_map matters a lot, for example, if you run tolower and then run the next line removeNumbers, it somehow does not execute the tolower anymore, but switch to removeNumbers, I fixed it, it might not be the most effective way, but it works

```
Docs.corpus.temp <-tm_map(Docs.corpus, removePunctuation)
Docs.corpus.temp1 <-tm_map(Docs.corpus.temp, removeNumbers)
Docs.corpus.temp2 <-tm_map(Docs.corpus.temp1, tolower)
Docs.corpus.temp3 <-tm_map(Docs.corpus.temp2,PlainTextDocument)
Docs.corpus.temp4 <-tm_map(Docs.corpus.temp3, stripWhitespace)
Docs.corpus.temp5 <-tm_map(Docs.corpus.temp4, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#frequency
dtm <-DocumentTermMatrix(Docs.corpus.temp5)
dtm$dimnames$Terms
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
freq <- subset(freq, freq > 10)
ord<- order(freq)
freq
```

That fixes my problem, now all the tm_map preprocessing code works. 
If anyone have better idea, please let me know, thank you!